# mod_rewrite regex to rewrite parts of a url

Tags: regex, url, mod-rewrite, apache2

I need to rewrite parts of the url to lowercase.  I can rewrite all characters in a url with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [L,R=301]
```

But, I have a special case.  For example; http://somedomain.com/monitors/services/awe/awe-prod/awr02.awe-prod.a/Read_job_245/.  I want to continue to rewrite all characters to lowercase, except **Read_job_245** for example.  **Read_job_245** can be any letters or number in upper or lower case, and will always be the at the sixth level.

I can't figure out the mod_rewrite portion.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "I want to rewrite any level **except** the sixth" then this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^((/[^A-Z/]+){5})(/[^/]*[A-Z][^/]*)(/[^A-Z/]+)*/?$
RewriteRule ^((/[^/]+){1,5})((/[^/]+)((/[^/]+)*))? ${lc:$1}$4${lc:$5} [L,R=301]
```

(Note the URLs begin with "/" because RewriteMap won't work in  and so doesn't seem to work in .htaccess for me either)

It'll take the first five matches and lower-case them, then it'll leave the sixth as-is, then it'll lower-case any subsequent levels (if they exist).

If you only ever get to 6 levels (and the sixth should never be rewritten) then this should be adequate:

RewriteEngine On
    RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^((/[^A-Z/]+){5})(/[^/]*[A-Z][^/]*)/?$
    RewriteRule ^((/[^/]+){1,5})(/[^/]+)/? ${lc:$1}$4 [L,R=301]

Tested with:

```
/monitors/services/awe/AWE --> /monitors/services/awe/awe
/monitors/services/awe/awe-prod/awr02.awe-prod.a/Read_job_245/ --> No change
/MONITORS/SERVICES/awe/awe-prod/awr02.awe-prod.a/Read_job_245/ --> /monitors/services/awe/awe-prod/awr02.awe-prod.a/Read_job_245/
/MONITORS/SERVICES/awe/awe-prod/awr02.awe-prod.a/Read_job_245/AAA/BBB/ --> /monitors/services/awe/awe-prod/awr02.awe-prod.a/Read_job_245/aaa/bbb/ (using 1st rule set)
```

Line by line explanation:

```
#Enable mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On
#Create mapping to lower case
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
#Match URLs with upper-case characters
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
#Stop rewrite loop when upper-case is in the allowed 6th level
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^((/[^A-Z/]+){5})(/[^/]*[A-Z][^/]*)/?$
#Rewrite URL to lower case
RewriteRule ^((/[^/]+){1,5})(/[^/]+)/? ${lc:$1}$4 [L,R=301]
```